# OCIlib library.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c, unix, oracle-call-interface

I try to do select with OCILib. Here the snippet:

```
int oraconnect()
{
    OCI_Connection* cn;
    OCI_Statement* st;
    OCI_Resultset* rs;

    OCI_Initialize(NULL, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT);

    cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate("user", "db", "pass", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
    st = OCI_StatementCreate(cn);

    OCI_ExecuteStmt(st, "select foo_id from foo");

    rs = OCI_GetResultset(st);

    while (OCI_FetchNext(rs))
    {
      printf("%i ", OCI_GetInt(rs, 1));
        //printf("%i - %s\n", OCI_GetInt(rs, 1), OCI_GetString(rs,2));
    }

    OCI_Cleanup();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

I get no output. What am I doing wrong? Or can can I figure out why I'm not getting any output?

Comment: It's telling you that you don't have the source for library.c (which is part of the client library code). You need to use `n` to step over those particular function calls (the library has debug information, but because you don't have the source you can't look at it).

Answer (score 0):

Put LINES=YES into your 'proc' parameters.

It'll generate line number redirections to your library.pc